# vb.net math.round returns the wrong number with no decimals

Tags: vb.net, math, rounding

I am using this code for dividing and rounding two numbers and then return only two decimals:

```
   Dim mb As Long = Math.Round(((Endsize - startSize) / 1000000), 2)
```

however, this returns the rounded number with no decimals and not the correct rounded number... the number 53.3998 is returned as 54, where i was expecting 53.34?

Comment: I think you mean 53.40 and not 53.34 as expected result? Because 53.34 doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yes yes, 53.40 ... it seams that the long variable type was at foult, when i changed it to Dim mb = without long, it returns normally :)

Comment: How do you expect a long to have anything behind the comma? The error is obvious, though I also didn't see it there (but neither did I examine the code to every detail).

Comment: If you had Option Strict On you would have seen an error that may have given you a clue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Option Strict On

```
    Dim mb As Double = Math.Round(((Endsize - startSize) / 1000000), 2)
```